# How to enable sorting in DataTables (deferred load)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

*DataTables 1.10.12*

Sorting doesn't work for my [DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html) implementation. I use deferred loading of data.

How to make sorting work?

```
var hash_table = $('#hash_table');
var data_table = hash_table.DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  deferLoading: 100,
  ordering: true,
  order: [[ 0, 'asc' ]],
  ajax: {
    url: 'get_hashes/',
    type: 'POST',
  },
  columns: [
    {'title': 'BRC ID', 'data': 'brc_id'},
    {'title': 'HASH', 'data': 'hash'}
  ],
  dom: 'Brtip',
  buttons: [
    {
      extend: 'excel',
      title: 'report',
      text: 'Export',
      extension: '.xlsx'
    }
  ]
});
data_table.draw();
```

The result doesn't change if I click on the sorting icons in the columns header.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the deferred DataTables, the sorting must be executed on the server side.
Datatables plugin only sends the instructions to the server notifying the sorting order (`asc, desc`) and the index of a column to sort. The [datatables protocol](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) defines two special keys for this: `order[i][dir]` and `order[i][column]`.

Below is an example of Python function that finds a name of the column on which user clicked and sorting order:

```
def get_sortable_coll_name(message):
    colls = {
        '1': 'date',
        '3': 'project',
        '4': 'project_id',
        '5': 'total_matches',
        '6': 'successful_matches',
        '7': 'failed_matches',
        '8': 'status'
    }   

    if message['order[0][dir]'] == 'asc':
        return '-' + colls[message['order[0][column]']]
    else:
        return colls[message['order[0][column]']]
```

Then you can sort, for example, during getting objects from Django models:

```
sortable_coll = get_sortable_coll_name(message)
objects = Model.objects.filter(task=task).order_by(sortable_coll)
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding this after the buttons element, I use this to sort our datatables, datatables override db sorting with javascript

```
"aaSorting": [  [1,'desc'],  [2,'desc'], [0,'desc'] ],
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14091825)

Comment: this does provide an answer as this is what I use to sort in our datatables

Comment: Are you sure you use datatables for deferred loading of data? https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html

Comment: `aaSorting` is legacy option for 1.9 version, there is `order` option in 1.10+. I use it like this `"order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],` but it doesn't enable sorting for me.

Comment: we use the older version, sorry abou that, have you looked at `data-order` https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data#HTML-5

Comment: @MariusBrits the deferred DataTables was designed to be sorted on the server side, look for my detailed response below.